# Release memory at runtime when an animation played via AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, android-animation

I have at least <=30 images to make an animation. When i played the animation phone memory fully loaded. I got a message in log cat, like:

```
    12-26 18:01:48.335: D/dalvikvm(7385): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 5% free 44870K/47175K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
12-26 18:01:48.340: I/dalvikvm-heap(7385): **Grow heap (frag case) to 45.700MB** for 1048592-byte allocation
12-26 18:01:48.355: D/dalvikvm(7385): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 45894K/48263K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
```

**Grow heap (frag case) to 45.700MB**. 
For this reason, many lower virtual memory devices can't run this animation & application get crashed.

I use optimized **PNG** file to reduce the VM size at runtime. But still no change.I also wrote  **android:allowBackup="true"** in Manifest File, it helps much better. I play my animation like this:

```
private AnimationDrawable independentAnimation;

imageViewAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAnimation);
            // set the animation drawable as background
            imageViewAnimation
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demo_logo_animation);
            // create an animation drawable using the background
            independentAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewAnimation
                    .getBackground();


            // start the animation
            imageViewAnimation.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // for 2.3 devices & All runs well
                    independentAnimation.start();
                }
            });
```

Required animation **demo_logo_animation.xml** looks: 
partial:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv001"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv003"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>
    <!-- <item -->
    <!-- android:drawable="@drawable/logoani256_00004" -->
    <!-- android:duration="25"/> -->
    <!-- <item -->

    <!-- android:drawable="@drawable/logoani256_00005" -->
    <!-- android:duration="25"/> -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv006"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

<!-- remaining are here -->
     </animation-list>
```

I run the application in SAMSUNG Galaxy S3 --> result no problem. But in Sony X-Peria New
i got errors sometimes.
Any solution to runs smoothly in sort of devices?

Comment: Try adding android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest.

Comment: already use @nikvs :)

Comment: Check available memory before starting animation

Comment: @nikvs: how to check?

Comment: You can use Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory(); this returns the maximum available heap size.

Comment: what i does in else? @nikvs ..

Comment: If there is not enough free memory you should not play the animation:-(

Comment: +1 thanks i am working.. keep on touch.

Answer (score 3):

These images are likely just too large. The fact that you converted them to .PNG will not help you because the size on disk has nothing to do with the size in memory consumed. Images are loaded in as Bitmap objects. So let's say you had an image that was 1,000 x 1,000 pixels in dimension. If the Bitmap is configured as ARGB_8888, that will be 4 bytes per pixel. Run the math and that's 4 MB for that image. Multiply that times 30 images and suddenly you are looking at 120 MB needed for memory.

Either shrink the resolution of the images down, or load them in scaled down.

largeHeap=true is a band-aid to the real problem.

Comment: How to sets Bitmap with ARGB_8888 or other? Each of my image is 256*256 px, 5~7 KB in size.

Comment: @shihab_returns Not quite. If the image is getting loaded in by default as ARGB_8888, then that would be 256*256*4, which is 262 KB. See this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html And this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig